# ConnectionTimed Out exception while using salesforce create call

Tags: salesforce

Hi I am able to access login information using webservice api call https://lo​gin.salesf​orce.com/s​ervices/So​ap/c/21.0

then login response contains the serviceurl (https://na9-api.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/21.0/00DE0000000Inpm) .
then i tried to createcall to create an account using api then i am getting https://na9-api.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/21.0/00DE0000000Inpmorg.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: check that your firewall is not blocking it.

Comment: It's probably not what's causing your problem, but noticed you are using the metadataServerUrl. If you are trying to create an Account, use the regular serverUrl.